# coded sort stupidtable.js using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sorting

I'm using the plug-in [stupidtable.js](https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin), i'm dynamically loading in ajax data and values dynamically change. I want this plug-in to auto sort a column of floats from high to low every time a new ajax call is completed. Is there any way i can sort the values using a script? `data-sort-default="asc"` doesn't work when loading in table data with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The stupid table plugin has been updated to allow for a direct call to the sort method as well as a more semantic way to update the sort values of table cells. You can read about the changes here:

https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin#sorting-a-column-programatically